# How to generate local report in cucumber?

Tags: javascript, testing, cucumber, report, bdd

I am trying to create local reports from cucumber tests using Javascript.

Documentation does not say much about how to do it besides listing all plugins:
https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/reporting/

So far I have found way to publish my report thanks to some articles, but that is not what im looking for.

```
module.exports = {
    default: `--publish --format-options '{"snippetInterface": "synchronous"}'`,
  }
```

adding --publish creates report at web.

Anyone made local reports with cucumber in javascript and could help how to do it or what settings provide to cucumber?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the below in your runner class:

For HTML Report -

```
 @CucumberOptions(  features = "src/test/resources/functionalTests",    glue= {"stepDefinitions"},  plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/html-reports" },
    strict = true)
```

For Cucumber JSON Report -

```
 @CucumberOptions(  features = "src/test/resources/functionalTests",    glue= {"stepDefinitions"},  plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.json" },
    strict = true)
```

please have a look on the below link, it has very good description of different reports generation.

[generate reports](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/cucumber-reports/)